# Write a small script to extract ms-exchange audit logs in csv format?

Tags: powershell, scripting

**Background**

I'm using ms-exchange 2013 in my environment, and have a separate siem box which analyze logs produced by different systems (i.e exchange). The logs for exchange are internally stored and can however be extracted such as

> Get-MailboxAuditLog -Identity test-mailbox-1 -LogonTypes
>   Admin,Delegate –ShowDetails -StartDate mm/dd/2014 -EndDate mm/dd/2014
>   | Export-Csv “c:\test-Audit-Results.csv”

**Steps taken so far**

- Enabling audit on exchange
- Got the command google which needs to put in a script (above).

**My requirements (in algo)**

```
1) check presence of properties file with last collect time. 
2) If file is absent query the data from some period of time before till the current moment:
    2.1) Search-AdminAuditLog -StartDate (get-date).adddays(-30) -EndDate (get-date) | Export-Csv "c:\admin-results-temp.csv"
    2.2) remember "get-date" value to properties file
    2.3) copy "admin-results-temp.csv" file contents to the final file <admin-final.csv> to be forwarder by ALE
3) **If file is present:**
    3.1) Get last collect time calculate difference in time from present time. If time-difference is more then 1 hours ...pull the log again
    3.2) execute Search-AdminAuditLog with StartDate = date from props file, EndDate = current 
    3.3) remember current time to the props file
    3.4) copy "admin-results-temp.csv" file contents to the final file <admin-final.csv> to be forwarder by ALE
4) You can clean up final file <admin-final.csv> once a week to avoid over-grow. ALE will forward it from the beginning at that case.
5) Schedule the script/code described above to run each minute
6) Configure ALE in a File Forwarder mode to send <admin-final.csv> file
```

note:on part of ALE that part is already automated. No need for file-forwarding required.

I want to above algo in power shell script.

**CURRENT-CODE**

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Get-MailboxReport.ps1 - Mailbox report generation script.

.DESCRIPTION 
Generates a report of useful information for
the specified server, database, mailbox or list of mailboxes.
Use only one parameter at a time depending on the scope of
your mailbox report.

.OUTPUTS
Single mailbox reports are output to the console, while all other
reports are output to a CSV file.

.PARAMETER all
Generates a report for all mailboxes in the organization.

.PARAMETER server
Generates a report for all mailboxes on the specified server.

.PARAMETER database
Generates a report for all mailboxes on the specified database.

.PARAMETER file
Generates a report for mailbox names listed in the specified text file.

.PARAMETER mailbox
Generates a report only for the specified mailbox.

.PARAMETER filename
(Optional) Specifies the CSV file name to be used for the report.
If no file name specificed then a unique file name is generated by the script.

.EXAMPLE
.\Get-MailboxReport.ps1 -database HO-MB-01
Returns a report with the mailbox statistics for all mailbox users in
database HO-MB-01

.EXAMPLE
.\Get-MailboxReport.ps1 -file .\users.txt
Returns a report with the mailbox statistics for all mailbox users in
the file users.txt. Text file should contain names in a format that
will work for Get-Mailbox, such as the display name, alias, or primary
SMTP address.

.EXAMPLE
.\Get-MailboxReport.ps1 -server ex2010-mb1
Generates a report with the mailbox statisitcs for all mailbox users
on ex2010-mb1

.EXAMPLE
.\Get-MailboxReport.ps1 -server ex2010-mb1 -filename ex2010-mb1.csv
Generates a report with the mailbox statisitcs for all mailbox users
on ex2010-mb1, and uses the custom file name of ex2010-mb1.csv

.LINK

.NOTES
Written By: SOC

Change Log
V1.00, 2/2/2012 - Initial version
#>

#...................................
# Variables
#...................................

$check_collect_last

#...................................
# Initialize
#...................................

#Set recipient scope
$2007snapin = Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin
if ($2007snapin)
{
    $AdminSessionADSettings.ViewEntireForest = 1
}
else
{
    $2010snapin = Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010
    if ($2010snapin)
    {
        Set-ADServerSettings -ViewEntireForest $true
    }
}


#If no filename specified, generate report file name with random strings for uniqueness

    $source=c:\results-audit        
    $check_last = (ls $source).LastWriteTime



#...................................
# Script
#...................................

#Add dependencies
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#Get the mailbox list

$mailboxcount = $mailboxes.count
$i = 0

$mailboxdatabases = @(Get-MailboxDatabase)

$directoryInfo = Get-ChildItem C:\Mail-audit-results | Measure-Object
$directoryInfo.count #Returns the count of all of the files in the directory

If $directoryInfo.count -eq 0

{

#Loop through mailbox list
foreach ($mb in $mailboxes)
{
    $i = $i + 1
    $pct = $i/$mailboxcount * 100    

    Write-Progress -Activity "Collecting audit details for Mail admin" -Status "Processing mailbox $i of $mailboxcount - $mb" -PercentComplete $pct

     $Startdate=((Get-Date).adddays(-30)).ToShortDateString()
     $Enddate=(Get-Date).ToShortDateString()
     $check_collect_last=Get-Date -format HH:mm:ss


    $auditAdmin_search = $mb | Search-MailboxAuditLog -Identity $i -LogonTypes Admin,Delegate –ShowDetails -StartDate  $Startdate -EndDate $Enddate | Export-Csv “c:\Mail-audit-results\Temp-Audit-Results.csv”   


   #appending file to final audit csv file
   [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("c:\Mail-audit-results\Temp-Audit-Results.csv") | Out-File c:\Mail-audit-results\Final-mail-admin.csv -Append -Encoding Unicode 

}

}

else
    # if difference between last collect time and present is more then #1 hours collect logs in cycle / hrs
$Now = Get-Date -format HH:mm:ss
    $check_collect_last = New-TimeSpan $check_collect_last $Now

    if ($check_collect_last.Hours -gt 1) 
    {

    foreach ($mb in $mailboxes)
{

$i = $i + 1
    $pct = $i/$mailboxcount * 100    

    Write-Progress -Activity "Collecting audit details for Mail admin" -Status "Processing mailbox $i of $mailboxcount - $mb" -PercentComplete $pct
     $Startdate=((Get-Date).ToShortDateString()
     $Enddate=(Get-Date).ToShortDateString()

    $auditAdmin_search = $mb | Search-MailboxAuditLog -Identity $i -LogonTypes Admin,Delegate –ShowDetails -StartDate   -EndDate $Enddate | Export-Csv “c:\Mail-audit-results\Temp-Audit-Results.csv
    $check_collect_last=$Startdate

}

    }

    else
    return 0
```

This is my first powershell script; I appreciate If someone can suggest/review If possible. Thanks esp in regard to date functions.

Comment: It's going to be difficult to provide you with an answer, as there doesn't appear to be a question.

Comment: @mjolinor i agree I'm revising the question.

Comment: @mjolinor does it help now the last-line?

Comment: I'd save and use the timestamp of the last log entry read as the next starting point.  What's the AD module being used for?

Comment: @mjolinor In my case; I want the extract code to run if time-difference is more then 1 hour since last collection time. I want to track changes done by admin in 1 hour window.

Comment: Mailboxes are collecting new log entries while you process.  You can end up missing or duplicating log entries doing it that way.

Comment: Also consider that if a server is offline when the script runs, you're not going to get the logs from that server, and it's never going to go back and get the ones it missed.

Comment: @mjolinor to avoid duplicate I can use column called run-date in csv  file; I can compare this column from previous retrieved / search log. Its a nice observation as currently my code is not catering for the option of duplicate.